# Will there be data loss in Cosmos DB with multi-region write if one of the regions fails (outages)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use Cosmos DB with multi-region write in two regions and I need to know what will happen if one of this regions fails (outages).
Will it be data loss and if, yes, how much time will it take to recovery?

Maybe someone faced in his project with a situation when in Cosmos DB with multi-region write one of the region outages and can share his experience?
Was there any data loss and how long did it take to recover in your case?

Documentation says that that there is a possibility of data loss, but there is no clear information about how much data can be lost (such as a calculation formula or something similar), also there is no information about the time. "Given the internal Azure Cosmos DB architecture, using multiple write regions doesn't guarantee write availability during a region outage. The best configuration to achieve high availability during a region outage is single write region with service-managed failover."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability#what-to-expect-during-a-cosmos-db-region-outage

Comment: I suggest starting with the docs, since you're asking something very specific to the service, and this really isn't programming-related (and is off-topic here). Maybe this fits on ServerFault?

Comment: Thank you, I added a question on ServerFault. I'll delete it here.

Comment: The amount of data loss my can expect is related to the consistency level that you are using. Check the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#rto